# diferencias entre versiones de angular 4

Tags: angular, packages, cli, subversion

durante este tiempo he estado queriendo actualizar un proyecto a la ultima versión de angular 4.3.1

[image: version 4.3.1 de angular]

sin embargo el proyecto tiene la versión 4.0.0 de angular, quisiera saber si existe algún conflicto si cambio de versión. 
[image: version 4.0.0 de angular]

realmente quiero mantener actualizado mis proyectos de angular 4 a su ultima version y anteriormente cuando genero con proyecto con el comando ng new proyect
genera esta versión

Comment: Yo recientemente actualice mis proyectos y hasta ahora no he tenido ningún problema.

Comment: gracias por escribir, te comento que recientemente me pasaron un tema echo en angular 4.1.0 y también quise actualizarlo a la versión mas actual que existe pero al perecer dio error en las vistas sobre escribiendo clases quise busque soluciones pero no encontré ninguna, así es que tuve que volver a la versión 4.1.0.